# Is there any efficient algorithm to solve constrained shortest path problem?

Tags: graph-theory, shortest-path

Suppose there is a directed network with edges having two attributes, cost and distance. Now, it is required to find optimal paths between different origin-destination pairs that satisfy a certain distance limit and have the minimum cost. Distance limits may vary for different origin-destination pairs.

If we use Lagrangian relaxation method, k-shortest path or label algorithms, we can only calculate the optimal path once for each origin-destination pair. If there are many such pairs (e.g. 10,000 pairs), these methods will be very inefficient. Is it possible to efficiently solve this problem using a single-source constrained shortest path algorithm similar to Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: Requests to suggest an algorithm here are considered too broad here.

Comment: For example, is it possible to extend the pulse algorithm (Lozano, L., & Medaglia, A. L. (2013). On an exact method for the constrained shortest path problem. Computers & Operations Research, 40(1), 378-384.) to solve this problem as long as the constrained shortest path from a specific origin to each destination is determined?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the (Delta, Gamma)-stepping algorithm proposed here: https://dgrosu.eng.wayne.edu/_resources/pdfs/spaa22-csp-pub.pdf.

Here's a code implementation: https://github.com/akulaarora/parallel-csp-dg-stepping

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).